# Reading values into a List object - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: list, command-line-interface

Trying to load values into a List object, I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

(edited question to simplify it)

MyVec.h listing (essentials only):

```
ref class MyVec
{
public:
    List<double>^ MyVector;

MyVec(void);
};
```

MyVec.cpp listing (essentials only):

```
#include "MyVec.h"

MyVec::MyVec(void)
{
}
```

Form.h listing (essentials only):

```
MyVec^ TestVec = gcnew MyVec();
double MyDouble = 1.002;
TestVec->MyVector->Add(MyDouble);
textBox1->Text = TestVec->MyVector[0].ToString() + "\r\n";
```

I get the error where I try to assign MyDouble to TestVec: TestVec->MyVector->Add(MyDouble)

In the Autos window it says (amongst other things) TestVec->MyVector undefined value

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change should solve the problem:

```
MyVec::MyVec(void)
{
    MyVector = gcnew List<double>();
}
```

Class member `MyVector` is initailly null reference. You need to initialize it before using, and `MyVec` constructor is appropriate place to do it.

Comment: Correct!! It seems that this is different in case MyVector would have been int (or double). If I look in the books, I can initialize those like: MyVector = 200; rather than with gcnew call. This feels like creating a MyVector object?

Comment: int and double are value types, `List<double>` is reference type. Initialization syntax is different.