# Lists of Classes with a List - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, list, class, unity-game-engine

I have a problem to determine where my failure is. I think it has something to do with my list in a list ... but I am not sure.

Class:

```
public class ChunkTerrainData
{
    public int OriginX;
    public int OriginZ;
    public string ChunkMaterialData;
    public int[,] ChunkHeightmap;
    public string[,] ChunkInventory;
    public List<GameObject> InventoryGameObjects;
}
```

Code Problem:

```
public static List<ChunkTerrainData> ListOfChunks = new List<ChunkTerrainData>();
//Start()
ChunkData = GenerateTerrain(ThisChunkOriginX, ThisChunkOriginZ, WithChunkData);
ListOfChunks.Add(ChunkData);
//Update()
GameObject Tree;
Tree = (GameObject)Instantiate(Tree_a, InstatiateTreeStone_Position, InstatiateTreeStone_Rotation);
Tree.transform.parent = TerrainMesh.transform;
ListOfChunks[i].InventoryGameObjects.Add(Tree);   //some ListOfChunks
```

at This last line I get a Error (but the transform works well):

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I could also not do (as I get the same error):

```
Debug.Log(ListOfChunks[i].InventoryGameObjects.Count);
```

what works (with the same List):

```
Debug.Log(ListOfChunks.Count);
```

how can I store and access this type of a list in a List? afaik the assignement of "Tree" is ok (the Cast from Object to GameObject). Can you tell me what to do? :)

Edit: maybe it has something to do with this [List Initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164703/reading-values-into-a-list-object-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-a) - but I have no clue how to do it in C#

Comment: What is `i`? Obviously there's either a null object at that index or the InventoryGameObjects list is null of that object.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < ListOfChunks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListOfChunks[i].OriginX == hit.transform.position.x && ListOfChunks[i].OriginZ == hit.transform.position.z)

Comment: so the i should be ok :)

Comment: what is this "gcnew" in wich C++ lists out of classes have to be initialised?

Comment: It sounds like the `ChunkTerrainData` at that index of `ListofChunks` is null. Can you show us the function for `GenerateTerrain`?

Comment: `gcnew` is a `C++/CLI` keyword. I would imagine that it stands for "garbage collected new". In C#, it's just `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize your InventoryGameObjects field.  Here is how it should look:

```
public static List<ChunkTerrainData> ListOfChunks = new List<ChunkTerrainData>();
//Start()
ChunkData = GenerateTerrain(ThisChunkOriginX, ThisChunkOriginZ, WithChunkData);
ChunkData.InventoryGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
ListOfChunks.Add(ChunkData);
//Update()
GameObject Tree = (GameObject)Instantiate(Tree_a, InstatiateTreeStone_Position, InstatiateTreeStone_Rotation);
Tree.transform.parent = TerrainMesh.transform;
ListOfChunks[i].InventoryGameObjects.Add(Tree);   //some ListOfChunks
```

Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer as supposed was:

```
//...
ChunkData = GenerateTerrain(ThisChunkOriginX, ThisChunkOriginZ, WithChunkData);
ListOfChunks.Add(ChunkData);
ListOfChunks[ListOfChunks.Count - 1].InventoryGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
// ...
```